# Images in tags doesn't come from static server

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, advertising

I think that images in tags (like the Adobe logo) should be served by static server (http://sstatic.net as other images) and not directly from web server since the request of this images are sent with session cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true; we haven't had time to really set that up correctly yet.

<s>We're working on something big for Oct 7th, the first day of DevDays. After that we should have more time. Maybe.</s>

This is done. ALL HAIL [SSTATIC.NET](http://sstatic.net)!

Comment: Is it waffles? I bet it's waffles :)

Comment: That's tomorrow! I'm exthited

Comment: Good luck on DevDays !!!

Comment: Will somebody broadcast/tweet/shout on the internet live from the DevDays?

Comment: @voyager That would be awesome!

Comment: So what was the big thing on 7 October?

Comment: adding opera support.

Comment: Cuil. Checking out the Formatting Sandbox...

Comment: Lies! All lies!

Comment: I love going to the opera :)