# Sponsored tag icons are not served from sstatic.net

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, advertising, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Images in tags doesn’t come from static server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24694/images-in-tags-doesnt-come-from-static-server)

As discussed on the SO blog, [static content is served from sstatic.net](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/).  But I noticed today that the new adobe-sponsored tag icon is served from `http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/tag-flash.png`.  This is certainly static content, so it's probably an oversight (which is why I'm tagging this as "bug" rather than "feature-request").

Comment: declined as 'duplicate'

Comment: @Joel, I believe putting `status-declined` here is misleading. The duplicate is linked, and people should be looking there for the status of this bug.

Comment: Sounds more like status-deferred. Atwood said that they should fix it but they are busy at the moment.